# How can I display all my product names with product links on single page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have around of 3000 product in my website. I want to display all product names with product links in a single page in alphabetic order.

How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
  echo $product->getName() .' '. $product->getProductUrl() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below way to get **all products**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('*');
                         ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
 foreach($collection as $_product)
{
    echo $_product->getName();   //product name
    echo $_product->getProductUrl();  //product link
}
```